# WordPress running strangely slow! 20+ seconds and hosts says it's not them

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I ran this report: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/EOYhTHcoT/http://woollymammoth.co.uk

Its the main example.com that is taking ages to load nothing else. Has anyone else had this problem before? I've tried setting up cloudflare but it didn't make much of a difference!

Comment: Is this thing hosted on a windows machine? I can't tell from behind the Cloudflare CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a database connect or query delay. (Guessing connect).

Raw file http://woollymammoth.co.uk/license.txt always loads < 1 second.
But anything with a database query is delayed every few requests, like the RSS feed: http://woollymammoth.co.uk/feed/

I can only guess what kind of setup you have here, but it's time to troubleshoot that. Make a simple script outside of WP that connects to the db, and time it.

Conventional troubleshooting tips:

- Instead of a mysql/db hostname, change the data source to an IP address
- If db is running under your control, start it with --skip-name-resolve option
- Check to make sure your mysql server isn't logging queries
- If this is hosted on a windows machine, make sure mysql connection isn't trying netbios name/connect first

Answer (score 0):

The content to load form your site is too much probably more than 2MB. So first load time is expected to be more. But if you run your site on google page insights. It gets  a pretty decent score of 93, which is actually awesome. So nothing to worry.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwoollymammoth.co.uk&mobile=false